# Spring webflux: code breaking the reactive chain, which causes it not to be executed

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am currently experimenting with reactive programming and Spring Webflux. I am facing a situation where part of my code is not being executed. After doing some research I understood that when such situation arises it might mean that my code is breaking the "reactive chain".

Here is the code causing me headaches:

```
return getPlayerOrdersForAuction(order.getPlayerAddress(), order.getAuctionID())
        .map(el -> el.getWeight())
        .reduce((long) 0,(a,b) -> a+b)
        .doOnNext(sum -> validateOrder(order,sum)) // side effect
        .flatMap(el -> {
           return orderRepository.save(order); 
        });
```

Everything gets executed besides the save() operation in the flatMap(). In this case how am I breaking the reactive chain? What concept am I misunderstanding/missing? Since save() returns a Mono shouldn't it be captured in the main reactive flow by flatMap() and thus preserve the chain?

NB: please don't mind the horrible code structure, this is just experimentation.

Comment: Don't you miss a `return` inside the flatMap?

Comment: You need a return statement in the flatMap if you are to use bracers. Another thing to point out, `.doOnNext` is used for side effects, its a fire-and-forget operator, which means you will probably get a race condition with validate getting executed and then it will save even if validation fails .doOnNext should be used for things when you dont care about the result. Like logging etc.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a delete statement, I must have deleted it by mistake when pasting the code here. Thank you for pointing out the doOnNext() behavior, I thought it would always be executed before flatMap(). However, here the flatMap() body is not executed at all

Comment: flatMap won't be executed if the upstream flux/mono is *empty*. An empty publisher *shorts* any downstream operations. To protect yourself against such cases, you can use *switchIfEmpty* operator. For example, you can use it to raise an error instead of shorting downstream operations. Example: `getPlayerOrdersForAuction(...).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No order found for input player in auction")).map...`

Comment: @JosephhansBouAssaf, does your method has any subscriber? Is there anyone/any method who is consuming it's output? Try adding a .subscribe() or .block at the end of your method chains (after last flatMap) and see if it executes via some test case.